# Unable to connect access database on Windows server 2012(64 bit)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a site which is using access database. It runs properly on local machine (32-bit Windows 7). When I publish it on Windows Server 2012 (64-bit), it gives me an error while connecting to the database

> "Object reference not set".

Tried the following:
`Enable32biton64bit ="true"` in iis. Executed `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` also, but the error still occurs. Why? How do I remove this error step by step?

Comment: You need to log/debug your code. Object reference error means that something is not initialized at the time when you are trying to use its value.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of access database are you using? Is it a mdb or a accdb file?

Here are all possible connectionstring:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

If you are using the old jet provider to access the database this could be a solution:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments/